# Socket instead of a ServerSocket

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

Although ServerSocket class is designed to generically listen for incoming connections, Can I just use a Socket object instead and retrieve incoming data in java? If yes, then is there any additional precautions that i need to take in doing so?

Edit: Thanks for the answers...but although in UDP there is only one socket class--DatagramSocket right?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using a ServerSocket?

Comment: Just curiosity, sorry. This has been pricking me for quite a while :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ServerSocket` is used to bind() and accept() to a local port. Despite the name, `ServerSocket` is not a `Socket`, it's only used to receive the connection. Once that's done, you get a `Socket` from accepting an incoming request, that is a communication pipe. I don't believe you can use a `Socket` to receive incoming requests without using some sort of connection receiver like `ServerSocket`.

Comment: And there are no additional methods that i could use to receive incoming requests other than ServerSocket.accept() ?

Comment: For TCP/IP, I don't think so. You can subclass it but the bottom line is it's always going to rely on the ServerSocket accept mechanism.

Comment: but although in UDP there is only one socket class--DatagramSocket right?

Comment: UDP is connectionless, so there's no `Socket` equivalent. `DatagramSocket` is akin to `ServerSocket` in TCP/IP.

Comment: From what i know, an IPAddress together with a port no. is a socket(in general and not from a java class perspective). So does that mean that DatagramSocket is quite equivalent to a socket that can both send and receive data?

Comment: Yes, a DatagramSocket is a socket that can send and receive data.  If you go that route you can avoid using a ServerSocket.

Answer (score 3):

Socket cannot receive incoming connections: only ServerSocket can do this.

Answer (score 2):

When using sockets one end has to reach out and connect to the other end (and the other end must be listening for that connection).  The end that is reaching out is typically called the client.  The end that is listening is called the server.

A ServerSocket represents that listening behavior.  Once your ServerSocket receives a connection it will create a Socket.  So you actually need to use both.  The server first sets up a ServerSocket and then waits for a connection using accept().  This will create a Socket once the connection has arrived.

In some applications the server keeps waiting for more connections, in other applications you can decommission the ServerSocket at this point and just worry about the Socket.

Unfortunately you can't have clients on both sides (unless you have a 3rd server which both are connecting to) because someone has to be listening for connections.